# css grid - how split evenly base on number of items

Tags: css, css-grid

I am learning grid in CSS to try splitting a row with this code

```
.grid-sample {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 4rem;
    padding: 0 5rem; 
}
```

From my understanding, the line `grid-template-columns: 1fr ...` helps splitting the row into 4 even columns.

Is there any way to improve this code such that it will adaptively split based on the number of items? For e.g., If there are 3 items, the row should be split evenly to 3 columns, rather than sorting the items into the first 3 positions of 4.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: with css only, based on items number, I don't think so. With CSS based on width, height, it is. With javacript, based on items number, it is.

Comment: @pierfarrugia grid has various auto settings which will adjust things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented with CSS grid, using `grid-auto-columns` and setting `grid-auto-flow` to `columns`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let button = e.currentTarget,
    parent = button.nextElementSibling,
    newChild = document.createElement('span');

  parent.append(newChild);
});
```

```css
.grid-sample {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 4rem;
  padding: 0 5rem;
  /* purely to generate content, otherwise irrelevant */
  counter-reset: childCounter;
  margin-block: 1rem;
}

span {
  background-color: hsl(250deg 90% 85% / 1);
  text-align: center;
}

span::before {
  content: counter(childCounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  counter-increment: childCounter;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-sample">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="grid-sample">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>



<div class="grid-sample">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="grid-sample">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<button type="button">Add span</button>
<div class="grid-sample">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fLcph0ka/).

It's worth noting that this does have the unfortunate issue of continuing to place new elements into new columns (as `grid-auto-flow` specifies), rather than wrapping to a new line when the space is maximally filled.

Given that situation, it may be better to use flex-box layout instead, for example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let button = e.currentTarget,
    parents = document.querySelectorAll('section > div'),
    newChild = document.createElement('span');

  parents.forEach(
    (el) => el.append(newChild.cloneNode())
  )
});
```

```css
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  inline-size: clamp(40rem, 90%, 1100px);
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-sample,
.flex-sample {
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  /* purely to generate content, otherwise irrelevant */
  counter-reset: childCounter;
  margin-block: 1rem;
}

.grid-sample {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.flex-sample {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

span {
  background-color: hsl(250deg 90% 85% / 1);
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

span::before {
  content: counter(childCounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  counter-increment: childCounter;
}
```

```html
<button>Add new child</button>
<section>
  <div class="grid-sample">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="flex-sample">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fLcph0ka/1/).

References:

- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow).
- [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).
- [`grid-auto-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns).
- [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).